# Apply all regexp_replaces from table sequentally to one string

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I need to sequentially apply all regex_replace's from the table to one given string. How could I do that with one SQL request?

PostgreSQL is 11.2.

```
xbox=> \d presence_regex
           Table "public.presence_regex"
 Column  |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default
---------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 match   | text    |           |          |
 replace | text    |           |          |

xbox=> select regexp_replace('Playing FIFA 19 Pro Clubs 2-1 LIL V BVB, 1st Half', 
                                match, replace) from presence_regex;
```

Select above performs replace to the original string and returns number of strings but I need the only one: the result after applying all the regex_replaces from the table.

Is it possible?

Comment: From your description of the table it doesn't seem that the match/replacements are ordered.

Comment: It's more useful to provide the table definition as `CREATE TABLE` statement, from which we can easily reproduce it. And some sample values.

Comment: After some hours it's became clear for me that it will be much easier to combine all that regex'es into one giant regexp.

Answer (score 0):

You need **dynamic SQL** for this. Meaning, you have to first build your SQL statement using data in table `presence_regex`, then execute it in the next step. You can wrap it up in a plpgsql function as single step.

**Assuming**

- there is a column to indicate the ***order*** in which replacements shall be applied (which is meaningful).
- you want to replace *all* occurrences, not just the first.

This function would achieve it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_serial_regexp(_string text, OUT _result text) AS
$func$
BEGIN
   EXECUTE (
   SELECT 'SELECT '
       || string_agg('regexp_replace(', '')
       || '$1'
       || string_agg(format(', %L, %L, ''g'')', match, replace), '')
   FROM   (
      SELECT match, replace
      FROM   presence_regex
      ORDER  BY order_id    -- column indicating the order
      ) sub
   )
   USING $1
   INTO _result;
END
$func$  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

It builds and executes a `SELECT` query of the form (example for *two* rows in the table):

```
SELECT regexp_replace(regexp_replace($1, 'FIFA \d+', 'bab', 'g'), 'bab', 'XXX', 'g')
```

Remove the 4th parameter `'g'` from `regexp_replace()` to only replace the *first* occurrence.

Call:

```
SELECT f_serial_regexp('Playing FIFA 19 Pro Clubs 2-1 LIL V BVB, 1st Half');
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=31deb73859a5e33ea021d95ecbf8ee2a)*

Closely related, with more explanation:

- [Store a formula in a table and use the formula in a function](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/34002/3684)

Comment: Fantastic, didn't know about that possibility. Thanks a lot!

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Comment: It happens to be much easier to deal with one very big regexp, so no need to combine it, i do it by myself.

Comment: Be that as it may, it has no bearing on the question as asked.

Answer (score 0):

based on Erwin Answer, a little bit of refactcoring. Since too much `select` a little bit of confusing. (for me personally)

```
create or replace function f_serial_regexp(_string text)
returns setof text language plpgsql as
$$
    begin
    RETURN QUERY 
    execute format('select regexp_replace($1 , match, replace, ''g'') '
    || 'from  presence_regex order by order_id')  using _string;
    end
$$;
```

obviously, pre-conditioin is the table `presence_regex`, column: `match`, `replace` must be there.